# Error: network does not support ENS (operation=“ENS”, network=“maticmum”, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.5.3 this error is comingabc

Tags: solidity, web3js, addresses, network, ens

When I try to access address as endpoints on getstaticpaths the error is coming
Error: network does not support ENS (operation=“ENS”, network=“maticmum”, code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=providers/5.5.3

Can anyone help me to fix this error:

This is my Smart Contract for store address of deployed campaings
//SPDX-License-Identifier:Unlicensed

pragma solidity >0.8.0;

contract campaignFactory{

```
address [] public deployedCampaigns;

event createdCampaign(
    address indexed owner,
    string indexed category, 
    uint indexed timestamp,
    string title, 
    string storyUrI,
    uint requireAmount,
    string imageUrI,
    address campaignAddress
    );

function createCampaign(
    string memory title,
    string memory storyUrI,
    uint requireAmount,
    string memory category,
    string memory imageUrI
)public{

    Campaign newCampaign=new Campaign(title,storyUrI,requireAmount,msg.sender,imageUrI);

    deployedCampaigns.push(address(newCampaign));

    emit createdCampaign(msg.sender, category, block.timestamp, title, storyUrI, requireAmount, imageUrI,address(newCampaign));
}
```

}

this is my other smart contract to creat campaigns  and donate function to send amount to owner who deployed  campaigns.

contract Campaign{

```
event donated(address indexed owner,uint indexed amount,uint indexed timestamp);
string public campaignTitle;
string public story;
uint public requireAmount;
uint public receivedAmount;
address payable public campaignOwner;
string public image;

constructor(
    string memory _campaignTitle,
    string memory _story,
    uint _requireAmount,
    address _owner,
    string memory _image
    ){
        campaignTitle=_campaignTitle;
        story=_story;
        requireAmount=_requireAmount;
        campaignOwner=payable(_owner);
        image=_image;
    }

function donate()payable public{

    require(requireAmount>receivedAmount,"Require Amount is fullfilled");
    campaignOwner.transfer(msg.value);
    receivedAmount+=msg.value;

    emit donated(msg.sender, msg.value, block.timestamp);

}
```

}

Here is my next js Get static paths function and I store campaign addresses as end points

export async function getStaticPaths(){

```
const provider=new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    AlchemyProvider
);
const contract=new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    CampaignFactory.abi,
    provider
)
const getAllCampaigns=contract.filters.createdCampaign();
const allCampaigns=await contract.queryFilter(getAllCampaigns);

return{
    paths:allCampaigns.map((e)=>({

        params:{
            address:e.args.campaignAddress.toString()
        }
    })),

    fallback:true
}
```

};
export async function getStaticProps(context){

```
const provider=new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
    AlchemyProvider
);
const contract=new ethers.Contract(
    context.params.address,
    Campaign.abi,
    provider
);

const Donations=contract.filters.donated();
const allDonations=await contract.queryFilter(Donations);

allDonations.map((e)=>{

    return{
        donar:e.args.owner,
        amount:e.args.amount,
        address:e.args.address
    }
});

const title=await contract.campaignTitle();
const storyUrI=await contract.story();
const requiredAmount=await contract.requiredAmount();
const receivedAmount=await contract.receivedAmount();
const owner=await contract.campaignOwner();
const image=await contract.image();

const Data={
    address:context.params.address,
    title,
    storyUrI,
    requiredAmount:ethers.utils.formatEther(requiredAmount),
    receivedAmount:ethers.utils.formatEther(receivedAmount),
    owner,
    image
};

return{
    props:{
        Data,
        allDonations
    }
}
```

}